# ROBLOX Lua - Wrong Rank colour being given to player despite having different color id in script

Tags: lua, title, roblox

Hey guys so I've made a Rank GUI system that can be seen above players in-game.

```
local billboardgui = 
game:GetService("ServerStorage"):WaitForChild("BillboardGui")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)

player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)

    if player:IsInGroup(4348965) then -- Set the number to your group ID !
        local clonedgui = billboardgui:Clone()
        clonedgui.TextLabel.Text = "Group member"
        clonedgui.TextLabel.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(36,154,136)
        clonedgui.Parent = game.Workspace:WaitForChild(player.Name).Head -- Yes, you can also just say character.Head                    
    end        

    if player.Name == "RealFancySmash" then -- Change to your name or someone else's!        
        if character.Head:FindFirstChild("BillboardGui") then
            character.Head.BillboardGui.TextLabel.Text = "Game Creator"
        else                
            local clonedgui = billboardgui:Clone()
            clonedgui.TextLabel.Text = "Game Creator"
            clonedgui.TextLabel.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,255,255)
            clonedgui.Parent = game.Workspace:WaitForChild(player.Name).Head -- Yes, you can also just say character.Head                    
        end
    end

end)



end)
```

So basically, the first part of the script gives group members the "Group Member" rank whilst the second part of the script gives me the "Game Creator" rank. The problem I am having is that the "Game Creator" rank receives the same colour (36,154,136) as the Group Member colour DESPITE being set to white (255,255,255). I am supposed to get a white "Game Creator" rank not the cyan colour from the "Group Member" rank. Thanks! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I guess `clonedgui = billboardgui:Clone()` is a shallow cloning: all the clones do have reference to the same `TextLabel` object.  Try to create new `TextLabel`object and assign it to `clonedgui.TextLabel` prior to setting `TextLabel.Text` and `TextLabel.TextColor3`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that the code is not reaching the else section that would turn your colour white. I'll walk you through what's happening below so you can learn what has gone wrong (or you can skip to the bottom I guess).

```
if player:IsInGroup(4348965) then
```

First the code is checking if the player is in your group. You as an owner are a part of this group so this section of code runs cloning the billboard to your players head and setting all the colours and text to that of a group member.

```
if player.Name == "RealFancySmash" then
```

Then it gets to the second if check. This is your name so the code runs getting to the third if check.

```
if character.Head:FindFirstChild("BillboardGui") then
```

Now as you have already had the billboard cloned to your head earlier this if returns true executing the section beneath it. As it returned true the code will not activate the `else` section.

```
clonedgui.TextLabel.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
```

If you insert this line of code under,

```
character.Head.BillboardGui.TextLabel.Text = "Game Creator"
```

you will find that your characters billboard is the correct colour as the colour change is now getting executed and hopefully this helped you with learning Lua a bit as well.